# Batch file directories and exe files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've read related posts on this forum an others for the past 6 hours which are close to my question but haven't managed to figure out a solution.

I'm looking to make a batch file to check if a directory exists, and if it does, execute an exe file within that directory. If the directory does not exists I wish it to check another directory for the same exe file and execute it. Furthermore I need to be able to execute the exe file with certain parameters.

For example:

Directory number 1 to check: C:\Program Files\Test\ if it exists execute Test.exe

and if this doesn't exist..

Directory number 2 to check: C:\Program Files\Test2\ if it exists execute Test.exe

Hope the information is sufficient, thanks in advance!

Comment: So, the `test.exe` file is not properly into the directory whose are you checking its existence, isn't it? Please, clarify this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files\Test\" (
   cd /d "C:\Program Files\Test\"
   "text.exe" param1 param2
 ) else (
   if exist "C:\Program Files\Test2\" cd /d "C:\Program Files\Test2\" & "text.exe" param1 param2
)
pause
```

Comment: This worked out partially for me. It managed to locate the correct folder but refused to run the exe file due to the parameters not working. However after changing the execution of the exe to just cd the directory and then later starting it with "start test.exe param1" it worked brilliantly? Any clue as to why?

Comment: Your program must have support files in the home directory which it can't find unless you CD to the folder.  I edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist c:\windows echo true
```

This will match a file or folder. to see if a folder or not

```
pushd c:\windows&if not errorlevel 1 echo Is a folder
```

But why not just direct instead of stupidly testing things.

```
C:\windows\notepad.exe&if not errorlevel 1 c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

or

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe||c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe||Echo Neither File Found
```

---

```
& seperates commands on a line.

&& executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

|| (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

> output to a file

>> append output to a file

< input from a file

| output of one command into the input of another command

^ escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach if you want to check for a specific path ..

```
  @echo off

  Set path1=C:\Program Files\Test

  Set path2=C:\Program Files\Test2

  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  for /r c: %%a in (*) do (

          call :check "%%~pa"

  )

  :check

  If "%~1"=="!path1!" (

        Call "!path1!\test.exe"

  )

  If "%~1"=="!path2!" (

         Call "!path2!\test.exe"

  )
```